# Guzzle Async process response as it comes in

Tags: php, guzzle6, domcrawler

I've been working on a script that makes close to a thousand async requests using getAsync and Promise\Settle. Each page requested it then parsed using Symphony crawler filter method (Also slow but a separate issue.)

My code looks something like this:

```php
$requestArray = [];
$request = new Client($url);

foreach ($thousandItemArray as $item) {
    $requestArray[] = $request->getAsync(null, $query);
}

$results = Promise\settle($request)->wait(true);
foreach ($results as $item) {
    $item->crawl();
}
```

Is there a way I can crawl the requested pages as they come in rather than waiting for them all and then crawling. Am i right in thinking this would speed things up if possible?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Sure! Take a look at callbacks!
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/clients.html#asynchronous-response-handling
You can essentially specify what to do as soon as the results of each of the requests are ready. (Could be a closure or a named function)

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for. Hope it's in Guzzle 6! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. `getAsync()` returns a promise, so you can assign an action to it using `->then()`.

```
$promisesList[] = $request->getAsync(/* ... */)->then(
    function (Response $resp) {
        // Do whatever you want right after the response is available.
    }
);

$results = Promise\settle($request)->wait(true);
```

P.S.

Probably you want to limit the concurrency level to some number of requests (not to start all the requests at once). If yes, use [`each_limit()`](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/master/src/functions.php#L386) function instead of `settle`. And vote for [my PR](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/pull/70) to be able to use `settle_limit()` ;)

Comment: Thank you! Just what i was looking for.